# Detail record not getting linked with Master record

Tags: apex, master-detail

We have a master-detail object relationship . 
Master record already exists and while creating the Detail record , Master record needs to be selected from a lookup in Detail record.

But the detail record is not showing up in the related list of master record.

What could be the issue ? What should I start checking?

Comment: the particular records are not visible or the related list. Also it is not visible to system admin or any other user

Comment: @TusharSharma- Records are visible but it's not showing up in the related list.

Comment: is the related list is visible. Also it will be helpful if you can share some screenshots.